# iOS alternative to CFHostStartInfoResolution using public dns server?

Tags: ios, dns

My application seems to work fine most of the time.

When it runs in China, however, it sometimes fails to give me my the IP address of our server. I use this to get the IP address, asynchronously:

```
//...
CFStringRef hostAddress = CFStringCreateWithCString( kCFAllocatorDefault, hostAddressStr, kCFStringEncodingASCII );
CFHostRef theHostRef = CFHostCreateWithName( kCFAllocatorDefault, hostAddress   );
CFRelease(hostAddress);

CFHostClientContext context;
context.version = 0;
context.retain = nil;
context.release = nil;
context.copyDescription = nil;
context.info = self;
Boolean set_ok = CFHostSetClient( theHostRef, myCFHostClientCallBack, &context );
CFStreamError cfError;
CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop( theHostRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
Boolean is_resolving = CFHostStartInfoResolution( theHostRef, kCFHostAddresses, &cfError );
//...
void myCFHostClientCallBack( CFHostRef theHost, CFHostInfoType typeInfo, const CFStreamError *error, void* info) {
    int count = CFArrayGetCount(arrayRef);
    for( int index = 0; index < count; ++index ) {
         CFDataRef saData = (CFDataRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(arrayRef, index);
         struct sockaddr_in*  remoteAddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)CFDataGetBytePtr(saData);
         if( remoteAddr != NULL)  {
            char* addressString = inet_ntoa(remoteAddr->sin_addr);
            if( addressString != NULL) {
                if( resolvedAddressString == NULL ) {
                   resolvedAddressString = addressString;
                }
            }
         }
     }
     // ...
}
```

I suspect that iOS performs a domain name to ip address lookup using whatever DNS is locally available, but I have strong suspicions that that DNS fails for some reason, some of the time.

Is there a easy way for me to make a similar query using a public dns server, such as google, in case the ISP provided DNS server fails to return the IP address of our server?
I have not found an API for this, so if possible, I'd like to have some link to some simple sample code to acheive this.

Comment: A question: is the lookup performed async? If not, how would you do that? I guess somewhere about the run loops...

Comment: Yes, lookup is asynchronous, scheduled in the runloop.