# DNS lookup asynchronously

Tags: ios, multithreading, asynchronous, dns

There is a piece of code that does DNS lookups using CFHostStartInfoResolution(). However this is synchronously and thus blocks anything before it returns - it's bad and I also think it causes crashes due to timeouts when connection is weak (when its bad it fails out safely directly)

So I want to do this asynchronously, as it's supposed to in the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFHostRef/Reference/reference.html
**New docs URL 20190227**: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork/cfhostref

Specifically it says:

> If you want to resolve the host asynchronously. call CFHostSetClient
>   to associate your client context and user-defined callback function
>   with the host. Then call CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop to schedule the
>   host on a run loop.

However this put me off because I haven't coded C in ages and can't get callbacks and runloops/threading right.

How am I supposed to call CFHostSetClient, CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop, and how do I implement those callbacks? Do I need to start a new thread?

Comment: This puts me in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16570001/129202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this

```
CFHostSetClient(host, callbackFunction, hostContext);
CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop(host, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
CFHostStartInfoResolution(host, kCFHostAddresses, 0);
```

And callbackFunction

```
void callbackFunction(CFHostRef theHost, CFHostInfoType typeInfo, const CFStreamError *error, void *info) {
    // Do something
}
```

You don't need to start a new thread, system will do it for you.

Comment: Ok thanks I got it to work. I think... I could pass the caller as a parameter in hostContext so I could call back to the flow on completion from callbackFunction. Something like this:
`CFHostClientContext cfhostclientcontext;
 cfhostclientcontext.version = 0;
 cfhostclientcontext.retain = nil;
 cfhostclientcontext.release = nil;
 cfhostclientcontext.copyDescription = nil;
 cfhostclientcontext.info = self;`

Comment: `CFHostSetClient(host, callbackFunction, & cfhostclientcontext);`  then cast `info` to `self`'s type in callbackFunction. Thanks @Jonny

Answer (score 2):

Actually `CFHost` has a bug since on macOS since 10.7. Up to 10.7 it was possible to cancel a synchronous lookup calling `CFHostCancelInfoResolution()` on a second thread but since 10.7 this is not possible any longer (it just won't cancel the lookup). I reported that to Apple in 2013 (bug number is 13672880) but despite confirming it, Apple has never fixed it up to today.

Yet the more interesting part was what Apple suggested in their reply:

> The best API for host name resolution is **DNSServiceGetAddrInfo** 
>   and that's asynchronous and cancelable.

This API is documented to exist on macOS since 10.11.4, on iOS since 9.3, on tvOS since 9.2 and on watchOS since 2.2 - yet I think this cannot be correct, it must have existed, otherwise how could Apple recommend it in 2013 (10.11 was released 2015). I can confirm that this API also existed on iOS 8 and on macOS 10.9 and probably even earlier on both systems.

This API is internally using an undocumented asynchronous version of the otherwise synchronous C call `getaddrinfo()` which is found on all POSIX like systems today.

One advantage over other APIs is that you can choose if you only want to retrieve IPv4, IPv6, or both kind of addresses or you can let the system decide to pick the address family for you, depending on which addresses the system considers reachable at the moment (this is the default for most other resolving APIs).

Also in case a system has multiple active network interfaces (e.g. cable + WiFi or WiFi + mobile), you can pick the interface to use as different DNS settings may be set on different interfaces (and different DNS servers can deliver different results for the same domain name). If you don't pick one, the system will always use the current default server (this is the default for most other resolving APIs).